# Raspbian Buster + Raspberry 3B+ = Drivers armv7l?

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, raspbian, arm

Estoy intentando instalar Docker en una raspberry con Raspbian Buster, y a la hora de instalar las dependencias, me di cuenta que el S.O estaba utilizando unos controladores para ARMv7l, siendo el procesador de esta raspberry ARMv8.

He visualizado la informacion del procesador y aparece:
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)

La velocidad de reloj si que corresponde al modelo comprado, 1.4 gHz.

No comprendo si resulta un hack el hecho que utilice drivers de v7, o resulta una mala configuración que si me dará problemas.

---

Las preguntas son: (Resuelta con la información posterior)

- ¿La configuración comentada es común o un error?
- ¿Debería aparecerme que los paquetes se instalan en su versión ARM64?
- ¿Debería aparecer que el controlador es ARMv8?

---

Parcialmente resuelto:

"A día de hoy, la Raspberry Pi 3 lleva un procesador de 64bits que podría hacer uso de instrucciones ARMv8 y tener una versión de Raspbian tipo “arm64” sin embargo esto obligaría a mantener otra “armhf” para las Raspberry Pi ZERO, Raspberry Pi 1 y Raspberry Pi 2 de las primeras versiones con proceador BCM2836. Así que han preferido, nuevamente simplificar y tener una sola versión que no saca todo el partido del chip de 64bits pero es más compatible y genérica. "

---

- ¿Que opciones tengo para utilizar docker de la manera mas compatible
  y sencilla posible en una raspberry?
- ¿Seria buscar una distro precompilada con compatibilidad con ARMv8?

--Encontrado :

- Ubuntu Server 18.04 ARM64 (Probando)
- Arch ARM (lo conozco pero no estoy nada familiarizado)

Comment: Cual es la pregunta aquí? Tienes algún problema evidente?

Answer (score 0):

En principio tienes que tener actualizado el SO de la raspberry.
Primero

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install curl
```

Los pasos a seguir son los siguientes:

```
curl -sSL get.docker.com | sh
sudo usermod -aG docker pi
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
sudo apt-get remove python-configparser 
sudo pip3 install docker-compose
```

Para verificar la instalación

```
sudo docker --version 
sudo docker-compose --version
```

A disfrutar...

Ahora mismo hay muchos tutoriales por la red de instalación y/o configuración para la raspberry pi.

Cosas a tener en cuenta:

1. Las imágenes de docker tienen que ser para ARM sino no te funcionarán.
2. Busca un gestor web de docker como Portainer para ARM y despegarlo por consola.
3. Ten en cuenta que si utilizas la PI con gestor de ventanas va a ir muy lento todo, te aconsejo que tires todo por consola.

Comment: Muy limpio y detallado, es un goze. Sin embargo aquí el problema fue que por defecto solo podía acceder a los drivers de armv7. Instalé una distro de Ubuntu para ARM64, con su versión de docker compatible. Pero en realidad, muchas aplicaciones necesitan de arquitectura x86, finalmente migre el proyecto a una VPS, y las raspberry pi la tengo pendiente de instalar un IDS o alguna aplicación de monitoreo de red, y también se me quedará corta...
Me ha llamado la atención Portainer, le echaré un vistazo a ver si me facilita la introducción a docker.

Comment: Yo tengo una Pi 4 instalada con Raspbian y Docker & docker-compose que la uso para trastear y hacer los deploy de las web que voy haciendo en nodejs... a traves de github y va muy bien. No creo que tengas problema en hacer un monitoreo de red, da para mucho juego la Pi... !!! Saludos.

Pd. Si te valió la respuesta dale un like.. !!

Enlace de tuto [portainer](https://domology.es/instalacion-docker-parte-1-dockerportainer/)